# How to split a span tag?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

What's the problem I've been having recently with the editor?

I have a span

```
<span>123456789<span>
```

I selected 456 regions for segmentation and I want to achieve this effect

```
<span>123</span>456<span>789</span>
```

what should I do?

1.Select with mouse
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQ6p6.png)

2.Click bold
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQc2D.png)

3.Split effect
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWiIv.png)

Comment: what if the length of the string is not 9?

Comment: what editor? what have you tried?

Comment: Select the area with the cursor.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "segmentation", but if you're trying to break the text up into separate spans, wouldn't a result of `<span>123</span><span>456</span><span>789</span>` make more sense?

Comment: So, you want to enclose the unselected string into `span`?

Comment: I want to make a simple version of word.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a way! ! !

```js
window.onload = function(){
  var oBtn = document.querySelector('#btn');
  oBtn.onclick = function(){
    var range = getRangeAt();
    console.log(range.commonAncestorContainer.parentNode.nodeName);
    document.execCommand('RemoveFormat');
    range = getRangeAt();
    console.log(range.commonAncestorContainer.parentNode.nodeName);
  }
}

function getRangeAt(win) {
    var _selection, //选取对象
        _range //光标对象
    ;
    win = win || window; //获取创建光标的域
    //html5得到光标的处理
    if (win.getSelection) {
        _selection = win.getSelection(); //获取选取对象
        //当获取选取中有光标的处理
        if (_selection.rangeCount) {
            _range = _selection.getRangeAt(0); //返回选区的处理
        }
    }
    //ie系列的处理，ie系列不支持win.getSelection，有自己独特的属性
    else {
        _selection = win.document.selection; //获取选取对象
        _range = _selection.createRange(); //光标对象
    }
    return _range; //光标的处理
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div contenteditable="true"> 
    <span style="font-weight:bold">Selected part</span>
  </div>
  <button id="btn">split</button>
</body>
</html>
```